# Error 110 sending email with mailgun on django heroku

Tags: python, django, email, heroku, mailgun

My settings.py:

```
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.mailgun.org"
MAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ["MAILGUN_SMTP_LOGIN"]
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ["MAILGUN_SMTP_PASSWORD"]
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

My views.py:

```
import re
import os
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
import time
import secrets

from .models import User
from .models import EmailConfirmation

from django.core.mail import send_mail

from threading import Thread
import threading

noReply = re.sub(".*@", "noreply@", os.environ["MAILGUN_SMTP_LOGIN"])

def threadingSendMail(subject, message, from_email, recipientList):
    send_mail(
        subject=subject,
        message=message,
        from_email=from_email,
        recipient_list=recipientList
    )

def wait(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        password = request.POST["password"]
        email = request.POST["email"]
        if not re.match(r"[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+", email):
            return HttpResponse("Email not valid")
        else:
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                return HttpResponse("Email already exists")
            else:
                theUser = User.objects.create(email=email, password=make_password(password), confirmed=False)

                hashKey = secrets.token_hex(16)
                EmailConfirmation.objects.create(email=theUser,emailHash=hashKey) 
                verificationLink = request.get_host() + "/" + str(hashKey)
                
                threading.Thread(target=threadingSendMail, args=("Email conf",
                    verificationLink,noReply,[email],)).start()

                return HttpResponse("pass")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("hello")
```

My error in heroku logs:

```
2022-08-27T10:55:15.473726+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread Thread-1 (threadingSendMail):
2022-08-27T10:55:15.473737+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-08-27T10:55:15.473738+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
2022-08-27T10:55:15.473739+00:00 app[web.1]: self.run()
2022-08-27T10:55:15.473739+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
2022-08-27T10:55:15.473810+00:00 app[web.1]: self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
2022-08-27T10:55:15.473820+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/djangocode/stocks/views.py", line 21, in threadingSendMail
2022-08-27T10:55:15.473912+00:00 app[web.1]: send_mail(
2022-08-27T10:55:15.473921+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 87, in send_mail
2022-08-27T10:55:15.474010+00:00 app[web.1]: return mail.send()
2022-08-27T10:55:15.474018+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 298, in send
2022-08-27T10:55:15.474128+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
2022-08-27T10:55:15.474146+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 124, in send_messages
2022-08-27T10:55:15.474235+00:00 app[web.1]: new_conn_created = self.open()
2022-08-27T10:55:15.474243+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 80, in open
2022-08-27T10:55:15.474326+00:00 app[web.1]: self.connection = self.connection_class(
2022-08-27T10:55:15.474337+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
2022-08-27T10:55:15.474458+00:00 app[web.1]: (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
2022-08-27T10:55:15.474467+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
2022-08-27T10:55:15.474589+00:00 app[web.1]: self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
2022-08-27T10:55:15.474590+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 312, in _get_socket
2022-08-27T10:55:15.474707+00:00 app[web.1]: return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
2022-08-27T10:55:15.474716+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 845, in create_connection
2022-08-27T10:55:15.474920+00:00 app[web.1]: raise err
2022-08-27T10:55:15.474928+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 833, in create_connection
2022-08-27T10:55:15.475117+00:00 app[web.1]: sock.connect(sa)
2022-08-27T10:55:15.475157+00:00 app[web.1]: TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

As the title says, I'm using heroku, django and mailgun for this.

Does anyone have any ideas? The strangest part is that this does work locally but not on the Heroku server. Usually after submitting the form, it takes about a minute or so before this message pops up. I use threading so that the email can be sent in the background whilst the page loads up, the page does load up as expected, pass appears, it's just this error.

Comment: some servers may block access to external portals - to stop spamers/hackers to use this server. And this may need to use special module - sometimes it may need to pay for it. And sometimes mail servers may block access from some portals - also to stop spamers/hackers from these servers. Maybe you should check in Heroku documentation (or in Help) if it allow to send emails.

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.py use EMAIL_PORT=587 instead of MAIL_PORT=587

Django smtp is using settings.EMAIL_PORT

This is part from the source code of django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py where the *port* value is assigned

```
class EmailBackend(BaseEmailBackend):
    """
    A wrapper that manages the SMTP network connection.
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        host=None,
        port=None,
        username=None,
        password=None,
        use_tls=None,
        fail_silently=False,
        use_ssl=None,
        timeout=None,
        ssl_keyfile=None,
        ssl_certfile=None,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        super().__init__(fail_silently=fail_silently)
        self.host = host or settings.EMAIL_HOST
        self.port = port or settings.EMAIL_PORT
```